# How Do I Specify Variable Class for Each Column While Importing Data Frame

Tags: r, dataset

Can I specify data type in r for (like numeric, factor, character, etc) for each column of data frame as I import it from excel.

For example, if I have 3 columns (call them X1, X2, and X3) in a data frame (which I call X) and I want the column X1 to be a factor, column X2 to be numeric and column X3 to be character let say X (data frame) is an excel file, how do I import it into r?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend installing `readxl` package by Hadley Wickham and then loading it in R.

```
install.packages("readxl")
library(readxl)
```

Then import the sheet you want in R and specifying the names and types you want

```
X <- read_excel("your_excel_file_name.xls (or .xlsx)", sheet = "X", 
               col_names = c("X1", "X2", "X3"), col_types = c("factor", "numeric", "text"))
```

If you hadn't specified the arguments `col_names, col_types` then the function `read_excel` would have guessed the names and types. (Note that the result will be a `tibble` which is very similar to a `data frame` and I recommend using `tibbles` instead of `data frames`)

Comment: Thank you for you help. I tried this:       X <- read_excel("C:/Users/cuty/Desktop/DATA1.xls",# sheet = "X", 
                col_names = c("X1", "X2", "X3"), col_types = c("factor", "numeric", "text"))
 and got this error message: Error: Illegal column type: 'factor' [1]

Comment: @economia what data type is the column X1 in excel?

Comment: X1 is "double" in typeof(X$X1)

Comment: @economia So it contains many different real numbers. Why would you want to make this a `factor`? Factors are categorical variables in R. In your call replace `"factor"` with `"double"`